# HTML - displaying title attributes on page

Tags: jquery, html

The `html` below is working properly, but how do I display `title` attributes on the browser below the video, for each `<video>` element?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Projekktor Version 8 Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="projekktor/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- Load jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="projekktor/projekktor.min.js"></script> <!-- load projekktor -->
</head>
<body>

    <video id="player_a" class="projekktor" poster="https://i.scdn.co/image/00d97c99f9fb5872e9a44f06ae7e20fd011de125" title="Faust Arp" width="640" height="360" controls>
        <source src="https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/7f8e0f1c60eaa0817e07f48d5954887ca148ef37?cid=null" /></video>
    <video id="player_a" class="projekktor" poster="https://i.scdn.co/image/0d1460c036897175f4631e8480ea4a2217bf5447" title="Daydreaming" width="640" height="360" controls>
        <source src="https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/fbf970f6ee1e7d849de08017d3688406107c751a?cid=null" /></video>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        projekktor('#player_a', {
        volume: 0.8,
        playerFlashMP4: 'http://www.localhost:8000/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf',
        playerFlashMP3: 'http://www.localhost:8000/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf'
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: If you hover the video, the title text will display as a tooltip. I'm assuming that isn't what you're asking. Where do you want to display them?

Comment: on the browser.

Comment: @MichaelCoker below the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can get the `title` using `$.attr()`, and you can insert that as text after the video using `$.after()`

```js
$('video').each(function() {
  $(this).after('<h2>'+$(this).attr('title')+'</h2>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="player_a" class="projekktor" poster="https://i.scdn.co/image/00d97c99f9fb5872e9a44f06ae7e20fd011de125" title="Faust Arp" width="640" height="360" controls>
    <source src="https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/7f8e0f1c60eaa0817e07f48d5954887ca148ef37?cid=null" />
</video>
<video id="player_a" class="projekktor" poster="https://i.scdn.co/image/0d1460c036897175f4631e8480ea4a2217bf5447" title="Daydreaming" width="640" height="360" controls>
    <source src="https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/fbf970f6ee1e7d849de08017d3688406107c751a?cid=null" />
</video>
```

Comment: nice. could you please expand your answer using the full content of `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`?

Comment: @data_garden can you be more specific? I don't want to include your `projekktor` code, if that's what you're referring to, as it isn't relevant to this answer. Only the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem or provide a solution to the problem should be in either yours or my responses.

Comment: @data_garden ah bummer, I was hoping to find out why it was downvoted. Isn't really helpful when posts are downvoted without a comment as to why. Seems like it fits with what you're going for, too.

Comment: agreed. the thing is my ACTUAL `html` code is being dynamically generated, after some python code is run. so a html with `=" "` values is parsed, and then attributes are set. thats why I asked you to post the full `<script>`, to see if your answer should be inside or outside `(document).ready(funcion()`

Comment: @data_garden ah. It should probably go in `$(document).ready(function() {})`. From the sounds of your page, I think any jQuery code should go in that function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
video:after {
   content: attr(title);
   display: block;
}
```

```css
a:after {
  content: attr(title);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a title="To show">a link</a>
```

The fiddle use a link but it should work with all elements as long as pseudo-element are enabled.

The attr CSS "function" (lack of a better term) can only be used in the content property of a pseudo element.

It allows you to fetch any attribute value by its name.

You can then style it with CSS with minor restrictions.